# Workflow - Count records from a date list between two parameters date

Tags: sharepoint, designer

Good morning,

I have a problem with a workflow. One of the step is to get the number of holidays between two dates(StartDate and EndDate). I have a Holiday List.  I do not know how to get that number?

This kind of query is should be like a filter to a list. I  need to filter a list between two dates which are provided as parameters. So I need to count record between those dates.

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010 to implement this workflow. If you have any clue how to fix up this problem, please send it to me.

I am not sure If I can complete this task without Visual Studio 2010.

Sincerely,